# Malloc() too small buffer

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc

I am asking this question to polish my knowledge. I wrote a test code the copy of below.

The size of `char *ptr1` is `malloc(1)`. I copy 5 word on 3 lines. that are total of 32 chars in length. The output is coming nicely. I went through the code on `strncat()` function. it is also seems not allocating extra memory for copy purpose. also I am not adding any null character at the end of the ptr1 char pointer.

How this can produce right result? then this is correct?

```
int main(void)
{
    char *name = "First Set";
    char *ptr1;

    ptr1 = malloc(1); // <<== here the memory is allocated only 1 byte
    joinWithMe(ptr1, name); // <<== 9 bytes are copied
    printf("PTR1 : %s\n", ptr1);  

    joinWithMe(ptr1, "-Second Set"); // <<== 11 bytes are copied
    printf("PTR1 : %s\n", ptr1);

    joinWithMe(ptr1, "-Third Set");  // <<== 10 bytes are copied
    printf("PTR1 : %s\n", ptr1);

    return 0;
}

void joinWithMe(char *me, const char *him)
{
    strncat(me, him, strlen(him));
}
```

.

OUTPUT

```
$ ./ctest
PTR1 : First Set
PTR1 : First Set-Second Set
PTR1 : First Set-Second Set-Third Set
```

Comment: It is not correct, it overwriting memory after ptr1 you are just unlucky it does not crash.

Comment: Why are you only allocating `1` byte to `char*`? That should represent a string of characters, not 1. Why are you calling `malloc` at all? What is the intended result?

Comment: You're overflowing the buffer, which results in undefined behavior. Any result is possible, including printing the normal output.

Comment: @GIJoe : I guess the intended result is to study the behavior, and build debug experience.

Comment: @GIJoe He doesn't have an intended result, he's wondering why this doesn't produce an error.

Comment: @GIJoe, I wanted to test how malloc() and str_functions works

Comment: @Barmar: That'd be great if it was in the question! I read it multiple times trying to figure out what he wanted.

Comment: as they mentioned it overflows the buffer. Besides what are you trying to acomplish? first you append(not copy) something to your pointer and later you overwrite it with printf?

Comment: Read the first line, and then read _between_ the lines.

Comment: @fSazy Please don't misspell words in the title to get around SO's rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It provides the "right" result because you got lucky. The `malloc()` function does not make it *possible* to access memory, it finds memory and reserves you *permission* to use it, with a promise that no other code has that permission. The possibility to access it (if one knows of a nearby address) is there regardless. If the buffer is written to without permission, the results are undefined.

In this undefined case, if the memory beyond the buffer is not writable, you'll probably crash. If it is writable but no other code is making use of it (which is likely in your current case), it will appear to have worked without any issue. If some other code is making active use of that memory though, either that code will disrupt yours, or your code with disrupt the other, or both. The outcome of that disruption is uncertain (since it depends on what the code is doing), meaning undefined.

Comment: I knew this way should crash. But when I tested it is working. How can I properly test this types of scenario?

Comment: @fSazy generally you want to test this using a malloc debug library or tool, such as `Valgrind` (if it's supported on your system).

Comment: Yes, Valgrind show this. `Invalid read of size 4` . I was wondering why this happen when I wanted to nicely test the functions. :)

Comment: Performing your own test for things like this at runtime (meaning within your own program) is possible but not practical, since it requires you to allocate extra memory and insert a lot of extra code which makes your program run much slower. It's far better to code defensively against the possibility and then perform comprehensive testing with Valgrind before releasing your code to others.

Comment: Actually what the error will occur if there is a null character at the end of char* array?

Comment: That the buffer is for a C string (meaning it's expected to be NULL terminated) is unimportant. The only thing of consequence is that you have permission to access _n_ bytes at that buffer, and if you exceed it (for any reason, not just NULL termination), you've gone beyond the bounds of your permission. There's no specific error (though Valgrind may report one), because the impact is dependent on where the overrun is and what other code (if any) expects it to be for a different purpose.

Comment: is there a null character added once I use `malloc()` ? or else if I added a null to `[0] = '\0'` of the char array and then strncpy the null character at position `0` is destroyed, right? Do I need to add it again at the end ?

Comment: strncpy() will not add a null terminator if there is no room (based on the _n_ you provide), so in this case, instead of overrunning the buffer your string will lack proper termination. It's important to always make room for your terminator on C strings!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things nobody has mentioned you with regards to `strncat`. (I think others have done a good job explaining the buffer overrun issues.)

#### 1.

Both string arguments to `strncat` (in fact, all string arguments to any `str***` function) are assumed to be *zero terminated strings*. In your case the memory (byte) allocated by `malloc` apparently *happens* to be 0, so it is interpreted as an empty string. If the uninitialized memory contains some other value to start besides 0, then it would be interpreted as a string that's as long as needed to find a at the end of it. So in general, the buffer returned from `malloc` could be a very long string of garbage much longer than the amount of memory you allocated. If you want to allocate memory initialized to 0, use `calloc`.

#### 2.

The last parameter to `strncat` is meant as a way to prevent buffer overruns by specifying how much space you have left in the buffer you have already allocated.

```
// allocate a string buffer
const size_t bufSz = 20;
char *pBuf = malloc(bufSz);

// initialize it with either a short or long string
bool shortOrLong = ...
strcpy(pBuf, shortOrLong ? "short_str" : "longer_string");

// append a string without buffer overrun
const char *pStr = "_hi_there";
strncat(pBuf, pStr, bufSz-strlen(pBuf)-1);
```

Depending on the value of `shortOrLong`, the contents of `pBuf` will be one of the following.

```
|0| | | | |5| | | | |10 | | | |15 | | | |20  <-- index
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|                                       |    <-- before strcpy
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|s|h|o|r|t|_|s|t|r|0|                   |    <-- before strncat
|s|h|o|r|t|_|s|t|r|_|h|i|_|t|h|e|r|e|0| |    <-- after strncat
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|l|o|n|g|e|r|_|s|t|r|i|n|g|0            |    <-- before strncat
|l|o|n|g|e|r|_|s|t|r|i|n|g|_|h|i|_|t|h|0|    <-- after strncat
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
```

(I used `0` to indicate the null termination character, and blank (space) to indicate uninitialized values.)

Note that in the `"short_str"` case, the appended string fit into the buffer, so all of it was copied; in the `"longer string"` case, only part of the string fit, so that part was copied, then the string was still null terminated to keep it a valid C string without overrunning the buffer.

Comment: strncat was NOT designed for preventing overruns. It was designed to extract substrings. It CAN be used for preventing buffer overflows (very inefficiently) but you are better off using strlcat(), or equivalent, that was designed to do the job.

Comment: @Schigh, Great explanation. In this case, I need to have an extra byte allocated for null character before passing to `strncat()` right?

Comment: @fSazy, Yes, you always have to have room for the null character. That's why I included the `-1` in the `strncat` call.