# puts() displays the whole content of strcpy even if an overflow of dest occurs

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

After creating a char array of size 5, then I use `strcpy` to fill the contents of the array but with a string larger than the original size; then I use `puts()` to display the contents of the array an the whole string is displayed which is odd because I iterate through the array contents and it doesn't seems to me that the contents are stored in memory (but they are displayed). This is the code I am testing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str1[5];
    int i = 0;

    strcpy(str1,"Hello world");

    puts(str1);
    printf("Size of str1: %d\n",sizeof(str1));

    for(i = 0;i < 15; i++){
            printf("%c",str1[i]);
    }
    puts(""); // Blank space
    puts(str1); // Display contents again... Different result!
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world
Size of str1: 5
Hello   ld  [
Hello
```

The 3rd line in the output is the actual contents in memory (I iterated further to verify).

I wouldn't expect the first `puts(str1)` to display the whole phrase but it does, also after displaying the contents I repeat `puts(str1)` and the output changes which seems random to me, also the array size is only 5.

Could you help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: Overflowing the buffer results in undefined behavior, at which point anything can happen (including things that make no sense).

Comment: Note that this is also a case of a buffer overrun when iterating outside of the buffer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144159/5699206

Comment: strcpy sets a bunch of bytes starting at where you told it to. puts reads a bunch of bytes starting at where you told it to. Neither strcpy nor puts knows whether that area actually belongs to you or someone else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Malloc() too small buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531964/malloc-too-small-buffer)

Answer (score 6):

strcpy doesn't know about the length of arrays/strings. It just keeps going until the string is copied (till a null character is hit).

This writes into memory you haven't allocated and is not guaranteed to return consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

strcpy does not know how many characters to copy as mentioned by other engineer. You have to use strncpy() function, and then terminate the string by `str1[4]='\0';`  since 4 is the index of 5 th character, which is max size. Else the program may crash inconsistently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char str1[6];
strncpy(str1,"Hello world",5);
str1[5] = 0;
```

This works by using `strncpy`. You have to tell `strncpy` how many characters to actually copy. Also, you must mark the end of the string with a null (0). That is what the last line does. Note that `str1[6]` must have enough storage for your string plus the terminating null character.